# keyboard enters quotes and single quotes only after 2nd keypress

Tags: keyboard, dead-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weird problem in windows XP - apostrophes and double quotes don't show up until the key has been pressed twice.](https://superuser.com/questions/122625/weird-problem-in-windows-xp-apostrophes-and-double-quotes-dont-show-up-until-t)

hello,
if i press the key for single quotes or double quotes on my keyboard it enters them only after the 2nd time i press them.

i am on win7 64bit and using a US-engl keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows thinks you have an International English keyboard; what you're seeing is called "dead keys" and is intended to allow you to, e.g., type the character ö by pressing "o.

To fix this, double-check that Windows is actually set to "US English" keyboard.  If that fails, run a quick search for "windows disable dead keys" and you'll find many options for how to do so.  (I had to do this myself when I got this laptop, but I don't recall which specific page showed me how, so I can't provide a recommendation for it.)

Comment: thanks. yes it is set to us english. couldnt find any helpful link on how to disable those dead keys but will keep googling...