# My windows keyboard is being "clever" with the quote keys - how can I stop it?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, input-languages

I'm using windows 7 on a laptop. On the laptop keyboard, for some reason, the quote key (which has both double and single quote on it) is doing some "clever" annoying things:

1. When I press single-quote (or double-quote), windows doesn't send any characters until I press it twice (resulting in `''` or `""`)
2. When I press it before a vowel, I get some kind of accented character. As I usually only write English, this is annoying.

The backtick/tilde key is subject to similar behaviour.

**This is not a duplicate** of the linked question because the two problems have completely different solutions. This question was caused by an internationalisation setting being activated; that other question was caused by keys being set to dead.

I have not attempted to set up my computer to process anything other than English. My keyboard appears to be (in so far as these things are standard on laptops) a standard US qwerty keyboard.

How can I stop this happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apostrophes and double quotes don't show up until I type the next letter](http://superuser.com/questions/122625/apostrophes-and-double-quotes-dont-show-up-until-i-type-the-next-letter)

Comment: Not enough reputation to post an answer, but the problem you're having is that the quotes, double quotes and tilde are set as "Dead Keys". If you want to keep the US International Keyboard but remove the "Dead Keys" functionality you must create and install your own keyboard (or download a ready made one) using [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339). I just opened the US-Interntaional keyboard, removed the dead keys functionality, saved and installed.

Comment: This is an old question, but by using an International Keyboard, I have access to other non-ascii characters.  I like it better than the old US keyboard.  The system is expecting and waiting for another key press to make an ä, or ê or ù or ç...  You must press spacebar after pressing ", if you want just the quote ".  The right-alt key also gives access to the International keyboard for € (right-alt 5).  Otherwise, convert back to US QUERTY Keyboard.  If you press "" twice, the result will return with two "".

Comment: Does anyone know the logic of what this was actually trying to achieve? How did MS ever think this would make anyone's life easier? How is it meant to be used?

Comment: A better way to solve it is to install linux, then you the user will be in control, not windoze.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

I would first make sure that your "input method" settings is set to "US" (and definitely not "United States-International"). You can do this through the Control Panel. **A restart may be required.**

#### For Windows 7:

1. Open **Control Panel**
2. Click on **Clock, Language, and Region**, and then **Region and Language**.
3. Click the **Keyboards and Languages** tab, and then click **Change keyboards**.
4. Under **Installed services**, click **Add**.
5. Double-click the language you want to add, double-click **Keyboard**, select the text services options you want to add, and then click **OK**.

See also:

- [Add or change an input language](https://web.archive.org/web/20110706010509/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Add-or-change-an-input-language) (archived),
  with video and hidden text (click on “Show all”)
- [Language bar missing from taskbar](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/language-bar-missing-from-taskbar/bbff6b32-e4f6-4237-b4d3-255a067c2bf2?auth=1), which appears to contain the same information

#### For Windows 10 and/or Windows 11:

1. Open **Control Panel**.
2. Click on **Clock, Language, and Region** and then click on **Language**.
3. If you don't see a card reading "English (United States)" in the list, click on "**Add a language**" on the toolbar to add it.
4. On the same row belonging to the "English (United States)" card, make sure there is a line reading "Keyboard layout: US". If it does not (that's the assumption of this answer), click on the "**Options**" hyperlink belonging to the same line, to the left.
5. In the "Input method" section, click on the "Add an input method" hyperlink to add a keyboard layout called "**US**". Delete any other installed input methods pertaining English.

See also:

- [Add and switch input and display language preferences in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027670/windows-add-and-switch-input-and-display-language-preferences-in-windo)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise that these settings required a restart to take effect.

Comment: Yeah, one thing I've learned is that it never hurts to log off and back on when you are playing around with the control panel settings, computer management, or windows registry (however annoying it can be :) ).

Comment: I stop and start explorer via the run window  "cmd /c taskkill /f /im explorer.exe & explorer".  Most of the times it will allow changes to many things to take effect.  That works on XP should work on 7 and 8

Comment: BEWARE! You will lose pound sign `£` (`AltGr+Shift+4`) by switching from `United States-International` to `US` layout, but it will solve aforementioned annoyance.

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to keep the International keyboard (for AltGR functionality). The only choice is to use [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) to create a custom US International Keyboard without Dead Keys.

Comment: "..and definitely not "United States-International." 
You just saved me from hundreds of hours of suffering. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, removing the other input methods was essential for me.

Answer (score 115):

In the case of Windows 8/10 (not the question, I know) - these accent keys are active when the keyboard is US International (US INTL), and will be deactivated if you change to US ENG.

You can switch between the two using the short-cut `WindowsKey + Space`.

Also, if you look at the desktop taskbar (bottom of screen) - to the left of the Date/Time display, you should see a tile displaying the current keyboard (in this case US ENG or US INTL) - click on it to bring up a selector.

Comment: Worked for me, I was working with Sublime Text editor and it was driving me crazy while programming. Thanks!

Comment: This is really a PITA when you're used to work with Mac OS ... Apple Key-Space means "Spotlight search" there, so I press it frequently in Windows ..

Comment: Left alt + left shift was bound to change keyboard languages for me in Windows 7. (Shortcut should be listed in the window where you add more keyboard languages). Changed to non-international map and it's back to normal, thanks.

Comment: In my case US Eng was active and I still had the issue. I fixed it by selecting International from the language bar and then immediately selecting US Eng again.

Comment: +1 The short-cut `WindowsKey + Space` is working in `Windows 10` too. Thanks :)

Comment: Quick solution without links to outside. Thanks!

Comment: "You can switch between the two using the short-cut "WindowsKey + Space"."  This saved the day for me.  Was on the verge of rebooting my webserver thinking that would fix it, but I'm glad it wasn't necessary. (This worked on Windows Server 2012)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it's much easier than diving deep into the Windows language settings.

Comment: In case it helps others in the future, I'll add that someone (perhaps family or a cat) must have accidentally changed my keyboard settings to switch between `ENG` English (United States) / US Keyboard the local setting (`NLD` in my case). The keyboard shortcut *Windows* + *Space* is important because I doubt many users _intentionally_ use the Control Panel to change keyboard settings (or at least not the ones who need to find out how to switch the setting!). :-)

Comment: Is there a way to disable this shortcut? The fact it exists as default makes me feel violent inside.

Comment: Thanks, this worked on win11 as well.

Answer (score 14):

You probably inadvertently pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd>.

This is a windows shortcut that affects some applications (examples include: mIRC, gtalk, wordpad, etc) and causes the behavior you are describing. Pressing the shortcut again or restarting the computer will disable it (and hence Dmnisih's answer is incorrect).

Comment: Does your list include cmd and xemacs running under cygwin? If not, then your diagnosis is incorrect.

Comment: SharePoint Designer 2010 is also affected by this shortcut.

Comment: @Marcin Anything that uses a win32 rich text input would be affected by this.  CMD does, and IIRC GTK running under cygwin does.  The diagnoses is correct.

Answer (score 12):

Windows 10 here.

<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> did not work for me. It changed between languages - not keyboards. This is how I solved the problem:

1. Opening Settings.

   - <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> <sub>(like India)</sub>
   - OR Start > Settings
2. "Time & Language"
3. "Region & language"
4. Under "Preferred languages" click on English > Options
5. "Add a keyboard"
6. You need to use the one which says "US" (not "United States-International"):
   [image: US keyboard]

Comment: I am having this issue and this is the only keyboard in my list :(

Answer (score 7):

If you press space after the quote then it will be as if you have only the one quote

Comment: Does this work with any key? Or just space?

Comment: any key as far as I can see...

Comment: yeah but pressing 2 keys to make a single key appear isn't the answer to the problem.

Answer (score 5):

It typically happens when one accidentally hits the left Ctrl and right Shift keyboard keys.

The way to recovery is in hitting these Ctrl-Shift keys two more times.

It has been illustrated nicely at http://www.pctips.smittystips.com/v_laptop_keyboard_errors.php

Comment: Wow, thanks! A simple fix for me when my keyboard was already selected as US English. I almost skipped your suggestion thinking it couldn't possibly be right! :)

Answer (score 4):

Here’s how I fixed it:

1. Open the Regional and Language Options control panel.
2. Click on the Keyboards and Languages tab.
3. Click on the Change Keyboards button.
4. Remove all the installed keyboards until none are left except English US.
5. Restart your computer.

Comment: Usually "International" variants of keyboards cause have this behaviour. Note that you cannot remove keyboard which is currently selected and the restart is not probably needed. (but Windows often surprise me with requested reboots)

Answer (score 1):

1. If you press <kbd>"</kbd> once, followed by <kbd>Space bar</kbd>, it gives `'` without a space next to it.
2. If you press <kbd>"</kbd>, while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and then press <kbd>Space bar</kbd>, you get `"` without a space next to it.
3. If you press <kbd>"</kbd> followed by a consonant, then you get the same result as (2). For example:

   <kbd>"</kbd>, followed by <kbd>m</kbd>, gives `'m`.

   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>, followed by <kbd>m</kbd>, gives `"m`.

Comment: What solution/action are you suggesting?

Comment: What I am suggesting is, the space-bar will do the trick. There is no need to change the Region and Language setting, 'because' this problem occurs, in general case, on any keyboard layout.

Comment: Your answer is really difficult to read and could be improved if you edit it and use `<kbd>space</kbd>` and `<kbd>"</kbd>` so that it formats the names of keyboard keys to make them easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for describing the misery of the original poster in so many words. Still, this is not an answer to the question of "How can I stop it?" Downvoted.

Answer (score -4):

For WinXP

Open RUN window (winbutton + r) type the following line and press enter

`cmd /c intl.cpl ,1 & taskkill /f /im explorer.exe & explorer`

Click "detail"

Highlight and remove all keyboards except US

Click OK twice and you should be done