# In Windows (8), when typing a quotation mark, nothing happens until the next key is pressed. How can I disable this?

Tags: windows, keyboard

A friend has an HP Pavilion laptop running Windows 8 and there is something that causes it to do nothing if you type a quotation mark until you type the next character, at which point it displays the quotation mark and the other character.

This happens in e.g. Firefox, Notepad, cmd.exe etc. and with both the single and double quote characters.

I don't know what causes this and am having trouble searching for information on this behaviour.

How do I turn off this annoying behaviour?

Edit: Sorry, right after posting this I did some more searching and found this:
[My windows keyboard is being "clever" with the quote keys - how can I stop it?](https://superuser.com/questions/346142/my-windows-keyboard-is-being-clever-with-the-quote-keys-how-can-i-stop-it)

Comment: Sounds like a bad keyboard try a USB keyboard

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, but I've found it's because of the "United States-International" input method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behavior for some international keyboards. If you follow the quote with a vowel it will add an accent mark on that vowel. You can also use the right `Alt` key as a modifier for entering characters like `ñ` or `¿`.

To change keyboards, go to: `Control Panel (Win-X, P) -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Language`. Select the language you are currently using and go to `Options`. Make sure your input language is `US` and not `US-International` or something like that.

To switch between keyboards (from within the same language), use `Ctrl-Shift`. To switch between languages, use `Alt-Shift`.