# Press once single quote key and get two single quotes

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Windows 7. I set my Keyboard to US-international in order to type French. It has worked fine for last two years but suddenly it changed behavior.  Now whenever I type a single quote, double quote, grave, circumflex or ... it displays two of them, just the opposite of what used to be when typing twice to get one. Other keys work fine, i.e., an "a" is an "a". I can use backspace to remove the extra one but it's too much hardship as I did even with this post. Besides, I can't type French any more.

I changed keyboard back to US and it works fine but of course I can't type French. I did the reboot (and install/uninstall US-int keyboard) and the problem persists for typing in any application - editors, web input ... Any one has any clue?

Comment: Does this happen with all applications?  Are you using a keyboard that can record macros or record multiple key events?

Comment: In all the applications I can type input - web browsers, word processors, editors, ... no exception with the same problem.

Comment: Check out this solution.  This might not be the exact thing you have, it might lead you in the right direction.  http://superuser.com/questions/346142/my-windows-keyboard-is-being-clever-with-the-quote-keys-how-can-i-stop-it

Comment: In all the applications I can type to input - web browsers, word processors, editors, ... no exception with the same problem.  Yes, I used autoHotkey to redefine keys.  But its setting has been the same for the last two years and co-existed well with US-int.  The problem comes up immediately after the reboot and before I activate the autoHotkey.  So I guess this is not a factor.  Otherwise I don't use any other key-redef application.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I've found the thread before I posted the questions.  But my problem is the opposite - one key stroke to get two characters. Regards, MC Chiang

Comment: - I reinstalled the system back to the original Windows 7.  All mentioned problems disappeared. In hindsight, I think the system had somehow been hobbled after the following sequence of events: 1. I installed web browsers from China (Baidu and KuWo), in order to download some Chinese music.  The browsers were needed because it allowed me to get inside (while those inside China try to go the other way) their famed national internet "great wall". 2. The browsers gradually infested my computer with very unfriendly adware. It also modified system functions.

Comment: 3. Finally I had it enough. But I could not uninstall it the usual way (such as through control panel, or run its "uninstall"), forcing me to manually removing directories/files. 4. My system started to behave oddly, including the problem I posted here.  Moral: this looks like cultural shock. Maybe I should use virtual machine if want to try the software from China.