# Windows 10 - International keyboard eats apostrophes but doesnt produce accent

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, international

I had this working on my old computer, not sure why I cant get it to work anymore.
When I switch to US-International keyboard, any apostrophes, tildes, carats, or backticks that I type are gone. However, Im still unable to write accented characters - the characters appear as normal, but

For example: eeeeee

In the sequence of es above, I also typed every possible accent character (single quote, double quote, tilde, backtick, and the shift+6 carat) and while none of them appeared, I still got a sequence of plain es.

Does anyone know what causes this? Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Apostrophes and double quotes don't show up until I type the next letter](https://superuser.com/q/122625/10259)

Answer (score -1):

Oh gosh, I've been struggling with this for well over a month and the second I post this I figure it out...

I coded a personal tool for some keyboard shortcuts that happens to eat the AltGr key. Apparently, the US International keyboard actually uses AltGr behind the scenes, even though you don't actually press it. I can typé pèrféctly fîne now, but with the caveat that I can't have my lil tool open until I fix it haha.