# Apostrophe does not work on my computer

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, desktop-computer, razer-keyboard

I am having a problem with my computers keyboard settings. So I changed my SSD the other day and everything got changed around such as old settings and presets. So I started running into the problem of my apostrophe key not working but " works just fine. I have gone through several solutions to which have not worked. I have tried switching my keyboard to English US - International and switched back to normal US layout, both did not work. If anyone can provide multiple solutions for me to try with detailed process, I would be very gratefull.

Comment: Does pressing the `'` key result in a different character being displayed? Or does nothing happen? Does `shift` + `'` return an `@` symbol?

Comment: No, i have my keyboard set to English - US currently but have also tried international same problem persists which is when i press the apostrophe key nothing happens but if i  press SHIFT + " that works fine as you can see.

Comment: Here is a similar thread discussed before, please check if it was helpful to you: [Apostrophes and double quotes don't show up until I type the next letter](https://superuser.com/questions/122625/apostrophes-and-double-quotes-dont-show-up-until-i-type-the-next-letter)

Comment: Hi, yes, i have looked at that post and a few similar, My problem seems to be an odd one.